# Azure Pipeline is showing green even if tests are failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using Azure pipeline and have created multiple jobs using `yml` file to run our tests. If any test is failing the pipeline is still showing green status. It should be in red if any tests fail the mentioned test suite.

Pls refer below jobs in green.

1. **Actual** - job is actually failed but showing green status in azure pipeline
2. **Expected**: - If any job is failed then It should be    displayed
   as red dot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9940J.png)

Comment: Can you share more details about the current pipeline settings and how you define the test in the pipeline(Task definition)?

Comment: which part-task or step fails, and what is the test error in the logs?

Comment: Are you using script task to run the flutter test? Can you try to use the [Flutter Test task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Hey24sheep.flutter) to run the flutter test? Will it work as expected?